# Relation among three tables: proper query and design suggestion

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, relational-database

I have three tables (MySQL):

1. `families` where I **define** the products' families
2. `products` where I **define** the products
3. `families_products` where I **relate** families and products

---

```
-------------------    --------------------    ------------------------
| familyID | code |    | productID | code |    | familyID | productID |
|----------|------|    |-----------|------|    |----------|-----------|
|     1    |  p   |    |     1     |  p3  |    |    1     |     1     |
|     2    |  a   |    |     2     |  a5  |    |    1     |     3     |
|     3    |  e   |    |     3     |  p1  |    |    1     |     6     |
-------------------    |     4     |  e7  |    |    2     |     2     |
                       |     5     |  a2  |    |    2     |     5     |
                       |     6     |  p4  |    |    3     |     4     |
                       --------------------    ------------------------
```

I have two questions:

1. Is this design convenient or is it better drop the `families_products` table putting the `familyID` relation directly into the table `products`?
2. With a design like this one, if I have the `familyID` how can I retrieve the `products->code`? I wrote this query but a query structure like this one would work if I drop the families_products table putting the familyID relation directly into the table products as said before, not in the case of a third relational table.

---

```
'SELECT productID, code, img
 FROM products AS a
 INNER JOIN families_products AS b
 ON b.productID=a.productID
 WHERE b.familyID=' . $families[$key]["familyID"]
```

Comment: Individual productID contain only one familyID or more than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure is fine.

If you have at most one `familyID` per product, then you should put the family in the `products` table.  You should use the junction table (your structure) if a product can be part of multiple families.

As for your query, it is fine.  I would use better table aliases:

```
SELECT p.productID, p.code, ??.img
FROM products p INNER JOIN
     families_products fp
     ON f.productID = fp.productID
WHERE fp.familyID = ' . $families[$key]["familyID"]
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, simple but great explanation. As you said, since each product can be part of one and only one family it's better putting the `familyID` in the `products` table. I reap also your suggestion on the aliases and I realized that my query didn't work not because was wrong but because I forgot about the aliases in the `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 0):

If your product only belongs to one product family you can skip the "familiy_product" table and add the familiy_id directly to the product. Only in case a product can be assigned to multipl families you need the "join" table.

With only two tables the SQL is quite easy: 
`select p.code from family f, product p where f.code ='xx' and p.family_id = f.id`